# LocalNofication sound in CN1

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

Neither on Android nor on iOS the sound file referenced by a `LocalNotification` instance is played (check the sample code below). On Android the system's standard sound is played. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

```
@Override
protected void postMain(Form f) {

    Container contentPane = f.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE));
    contentPane.setUIID("ToastBar");

    Button btn = new Button("create Notification");
    btn.addActionListener((e) -> {
        scheduleNotification(Display.getInstance(), 0, "Title", "Body", "notification_sound_file.mp3", System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000);
    });

    contentPane.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, btn);
}

private void scheduleNotification(Display dsp, int nId, String nTitle, String nBody, String soundFileName, long scheduleTime) {

    LocalNotification ntf = new LocalNotification();
    ntf.setId(nId + " " + scheduleTime);
    ntf.setAlertTitle(nTitle);
    ntf.setAlertBody(nBody + " " + scheduleTime);
    ntf.setAlertSound("/" + soundFileName);
    Log.p("scheduling ntf ("+nTitle+","+ ntf.getAlertBody() +","+ ntf.getAlertSound());
    dsp.scheduleLocalNotification(ntf, scheduleTime, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
}
```

**Note: *notification_sound_file.mp3* does exist in my default package!**

Comment: This looks like a bug in Codename One.  I have filed an issue [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2137).  It doesn't look like there is a workaround for this currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the sound file from device storage, then it can't detect directly
Instead of using this

```
ntf.setAlertSound("/" + soundFileName);
```

Try this

```
ntf.setAlertSound(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "Folder_Name/" + soundFileName);
```

This will locate your file and your specific sound will play. One more thing add "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission also in manifest.
Best of luck.

Comment: thanks for the quick reponse, but it's not the way it can be handled in CN1. e.g. `Environmet` is not available in the CN1 scope. Moreover [cn1JDoc](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/notifications/LocalNotification.html#setAlertSound-java.lang.String-) says so

Answer (score 0):

The sound file needs to be a path to a file in `FileSystemStorage` which must always be fully qualified. You need to copy the file into the filesystem ideally under the app directory see https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-use-storage-file-system-sql.html

Comment: hmm I'm confused, since when I pass a fully qualified path, I'm getting the following error: "`Alert sound file name must start with the 'notification_sound' prefix`" (which is also stated in the method's java doc). That's why I'm passing "/notification_sound_file.mp3".

Comment: Sorry I guess I wasn't familiar with that API. I'll ask someone who worked on it to look into it